# Try-Catch: How do I catch a value to log it?

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

Here is my code:

```
BEGIN TRY
update [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[SALESLINE] 
      set recid = i.recid
   FROM [Integration].[dbo].[CrmOrderDetails] c WITH(NOLOCK) 
    left outer join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[SALESTABLE] s WITH(NOLOCK) 
        on cast(c.salesorderid as varchar(50)) = s.CRMGUID
    left outer join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[INVENTTABLE] it WITH(NOLOCK) 
        on it.NAMEALIAS = c.productidname       
    left outer join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[INVENTTABLEMODULE] i WITH(NOLOCK) 
        on it.ITEMID = i.ITEMID
        and i.MODULETYPE = 2 -- sales order
    left outer join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[SALESLINE] sl WITH(NOLOCK) 
        on sl.SALESID = s.SALESID
        and sl.ITEMID = it.itemid
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
INSERT INTO [Integration].[dbo].[PackageError]
           ([ID]
           ,[PackageName]
           ,[PackageStep]
           ,[ErrorDescription])
    SELECT 'RECID VALUE HERE', 'CrmToAxOrders', 'UpdateSalesLineSP', ERROR_MESSAGE() ;

END CATCH
```

How do I get the i.recid value that errors so I can log it to the PackageError table? I don't see a way to determine which recid caused the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do you know what errors you are/will be receiving? If you know the error you may be able to search for broken records even before the try/catch.

Side note, your query uses left joins and doesn't link the update table to the records.
Could it be redesigned so that it only updates records that are found.

```
update s1
  set recid = i.recid
FROM [Integration].[dbo].[CrmOrderDetails] c
inner join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[SALESTABLE] s
    on cast(c.salesorderid as varchar(50)) = s.CRMGUID
inner join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[INVENTTABLE] it
    on it.NAMEALIAS = c.productidname       
inner join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[INVENTTABLEMODULE] i
    on it.ITEMID = i.ITEMID
    and i.MODULETYPE = 2 -- sales order
inner join [MicrosoftDynamicsAX].[dbo].[SALESLINE] sl
    on sl.SALESID = s.SALESID
    and sl.ITEMID = it.itemid
```

this way it updates linked s1 records, and only if they were found in the other tables.
Also, using WITH(NOLOCK) will retreive records that haven't been committed to the database yet, it is safer to only adjust values that have been committed.